# How to SUM an array containing numbers, empty cells and errors messages

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum

I have a list of places in a car (D1:L2) which are chosen for change/repair (D2:L2) let's say. All the prices for them are mentioned in another sheet (B1:J1 - car places and A2:A7 consist of types of defects) and in the area B2:J7 are mentioned the prices for a specific spare part.

In the column M in the original sheet I would like to add a sum for every single spare part which is mentioned in a line.

Here is the example of work sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y6mnjE5NN9tsY27MYgl9TX0R2tIWasQFP5ptyQ-u93w/edit?usp=sharing

My code works great until there empty cells in D2:L2. Code is:

```
=sum(arrayformula(vlookup(D2:L2;'Prices Spare parts'!$A$1:$J;match(D1:L1;'Prices Spare parts'!$A$1:1;0);0)))
```

Could you help me with a formula for summarizing all prices for each spare part for every line even when some of them are empty?

Answer (score 2):

It would be great to mention that your original formula works fine when there are no empty values in D2:L2 row. So you need only a small tweak.

Your original code:

```
=sum(
   arrayformula(
       vlookup(D2:L2;'Prices Spare parts'!$A$1:$J;
       match(D1:L1;'Prices Spare parts'!$A$1:1;0)
       ;0)
        )
     )
```

After adding IFERROR everything works even with empty cells:

```
=sum(
   iferror(
      arrayformula(
         vlookup(D2:L2;'Prices Spare parts'!$A$1:$J;
         match(D1:L1;'Prices Spare parts'!$A$1:1;0)
        ;0)
      );
   0)
)
```